# Can't seem to figure out why the code is not working

Tags: python-3.x

This is a program to convert my weight in Kg to pounds

```py
weight = input('Weight: ')
type = input('(L)bs or (K)g: ')

if type.upper() == K:
    converted = float(weight) * 2.205
else :
   converted = float(weight) * 0.45
print('You are: ' + converted )
```

Answer (score 0):

You check if the inputted string is equal to a variable named K. That variable does not exist. You can change it to:

```
if type.upper() == 'K':
```